# Deploying Mono MVC in shared hosting environment

Tags: mono, asp.net-mvc-4, shared-hosting

I'm not posting on serverfault because the application is under development and I need to test it in Mono, but it could be suitable there too...

I would like not to ask **if** it's possible to deploy an ASP.NET MVC website on Apache2 VirtualHost, because it is, but rather if it's possible without interfering with PHP configuration.

### The long question

Apache's default PHP configuration looks like this

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php4
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php5
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .php4s
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .php5s
        AddHandler application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
        DirectoryIndex index.php4
        DirectoryIndex index.php5
        DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

And this tells Apache that .php files are PHP scripts.

OK...

Now if I enable `mod_mono` on server, it maps .aspx files to Mono. And that's OK.

But when I enable the test host VirtualHost with a barebone configuration that is perfect for PHP (it's based on `mod_macro` if you mind the dollars)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.$name
    ServerAlias $name

    <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
        AssignUserID $user $user

    </IfModule>


    ErrorLog /path/tp/$name/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /path/to/$name/logs/access_log combined


    DocumentRoot /path/to/$name/htdocs
    ServerAdmin email@email
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I get a 404 error for the default controller.

I know I can, on my own test server, simply say `SetHandler mono` and voilà. But the question affects general-purpose hosting. Also, I could have the answer by myself: since there is no .aspx file in Razor-MVC (or better paths are mapped to controllers via routers) then I obviously get a 404 error for everything that Apache doesn't recognize as a file.

If I want to deploy this Mono application on a server run by a generalistic hosting provider that supports Mono, or vice versa if I would like to offer (on a production server) hosting for PHP and Mono too without having to change configuration according to customer's demands, **could I use an Apache configuration that both satisfies Mono and runs PHP?**

### The shortened question

How can I configure Apache2 **once** in order to run **both** PHP and Mono MVC on the same VirtualHost without changing the configuration according to language the application is written in?

Answer (score 0):

go to this configurator
http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/
it provide auto make config for Apache2, based on virtualHost.
Now i'm using mod_mono and mod_php5 jointly.